# How to wrap (surround) java matcher groups with xml?

Tags: java, regex

Using the following value of a text node...

```
MatcH one MatcHer two MarcH three
```

How can java matcher.find() be used to create the following output?

```
<wrap>MatcH</wrap> one MatcHer two <wrap>MarcH</wrap> three
```

Assuming a java regex that captures all words starting with capital 'M' and ending with a capital 'H'

```
\bM\w*H\b
```

Basically, I want to surround anything that matches this regex with **wrap** tags

```
String text = "MatcH one MatcHer two MarcH three";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(\\bM\w*H\b\);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

// replace each time the regex is found
while (matcher.find()) {
   text = text.replaceAll(matcher.group(), "<wrap>" + 
            + matcher.group() + "</wrap>");
}
```

ReplaceFirst/ReplaceAll is not working for me because it results in the following...

```
<wrap>MatcH</wrap> one <wrap>MatcH</wrap>er two <wrap>MarcH</wrap> three
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Also, I want to avoid hard-coding match numbers (matcher.group(1), $2, etc - because I'm not sure how many matches will exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is problematic since your do `replaceAll`, so it will match `MatcH`, then `MatcH` and `MatcHer` will get replaced in that iteration of the loop. Note that the `\\b` doesn't appear in the output of `group`, so nothing prevents it from replacing `MatcHer`.

You can put a `System.out.println` inside the loop to print the output of `group` and the output of `replaceAll` to see what happens and why it does what it does.

Simplifying your code to just the below will work: (that's probably "hard-coding match numbers" but I don't really see a problem with that as it stands and I don't see a simpler solution)

```
String text = "MatcH one MatcHer two MarcH three";
text = text.replaceAll("\\b(M\\w*H)\\b", "<wrap>$1</wrap>");
```

The above is how regex is supposed to work. If you see that problems may arise in future using something similar to the above, regex may not be the way to go.

Comment: thanks @Dukeling... I needed to use your suggestion inside of matcher.find() to get the desired output